# What does  symbol mean?

Tags: functions, notation

So the context I found this symbol in is a research paper where it was present as part of an equation. This symbol was never mentioned later so I have no idea what it means. Any help would be appreciated.

Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question.

[image: unknown symbol]

Edit: Someone commented that it might be better for me to include the name of the paper, and I'll do that. [The paper](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2019/papers/Yuan_Enhanced_Bayesian_Compression_via_Deep_Reinforcement_Learning_CVPR_2019_paper.pdf) is called "Enhanced Bayesian Compression via Deep Reinforcement Learning." Thanks

Comment: I think it's better to mention the paper name. It might be the normal distribution.

Answer (score 2):

It denotes the PDF at $w_i$ of a Normal distribution with mean $c_i$ and standard deviation $z_i$, and so $\mathcal{N}(w_i|c_i,\,z_i^2)=\frac{1}{z_i\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp-\frac{(w_i-c_i)^2}{2z_i^2}$. Such a distribution [is commonly considered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) in that field.